# Methods of built-in classes JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
const arr = [];
console.log(arr.constructor);  // logs 'Array()'
console.log(typeof arr.constructor); // logs "function"
```

So basically, `Array()` is a constructor function/class. 
Strangely, if you 'expand' `Array()` in console, you see methods like `concat`, `filter`, etc. listed directly on it (i.e. directly on `arr.constructor`). However, these methods are also listed under `arr.constructor.prototype` as expected.

So my question is, why are the same methods defined in two places?

Comment: It's not defined in two places, it's referred to in two different ways.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: That's weird. Are you saying that `arr.constructor.concat` internally refers to `arr.constructor.prototype.concat`? How can that work?

Comment: They’re a deprecated, Gecko-only feature from JavaScript 1.6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods.